# ¿Se usa coma antes de "respectivamente"?

Tags: gramática, ortografía, puntuación, redacción

En la siguiente frase, ¿es necesaria la coma antes de *respectivamente*? Me parece que no debe llevarla, pero he visto muchos ejemplos parecidos donde la colocan.

> Los valores de desempeño corresponden a 80% y 90% para inglés y español, **respectivamente**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Según dijo [la RAE en Twitter](https://twitter.com/raeinforma/status/981867876037677056):

> #RAEconsultas El adverbio «respectivamente» suele aislarse con comas del resto del enunciado. **No se trata de una coma obligatoria**, aunque,  en enumeraciones con varios elementos o de cierta complejidad, esa coma puede facilitar la interpretación del enunciado.

Answer (score 1):

Consultando el DPD, la única norma que podría aplicar, sería esta:

> [**COMA**](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=V1EqcYbX4D61AWBBrd).
>
> **1. Usos lingüísticos**
>
> **1.2. Para separar o aislar elementos u oraciones dentro de un mismo enunciado**
>
> **1.2.11.** Se escribe coma detrás de determinados enlaces como *esto es, es decir, a saber, pues bien, ahora bien, en primer lugar, por un/otro lado, por una/otra parte, en fin, por último, además, con todo, en tal caso, sin embargo, no obstante, por el contrario, en cambio* y otros similares, así como detrás de muchos adverbios o locuciones adverbiales que modifican a toda la oración y no solo a uno de sus elementos, como *efectivamente, generalmente, naturalmente, por regla general*, etc.: *Por lo tanto, los que no tengan invitación no podrán entrar al recinto; no obstante, podrán seguir el acto a través de pantallas instaladas en el exterior. Naturalmente, los invitados deben vestir de etiqueta.* Si estas expresiones van en medio de la oración, se escriben entre comas: *Estas palabras son sinónimas, es decir, significan lo mismo; los antónimos, en cambio, tienen significados opuestos.*

No menciona el adverbio "respectivamente" de manera explícita, es cierto; pero si haces una búsqueda de texto por "respectivamente" en cualquier (otro) artículo del propio DPD, podrás confirmar que siempre va precedida y/o seguida de sendas comas.
Se entiende entonces que **sí, siempre se pone coma antes de *respectivamente***.

Comment: Me pasó lo mismo: busqué por _respectivamente_ en el DPD y siempre me salía con coma antes.

Comment: It's not mandatory as [this](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31336/23419) tells, find a recent example in fifth TP.3 of [law 35/2006](https://www.boe.es/buscar/act.php?id=BOE-A-2006-20764)

Answer (score 1):

Viendo ejemplos de su uso en la RAE se puede deducir que al menos usar la coma no es incorrecto:

> Los sustantivos que designan la voz que emite el gato son maullido y mayido, respectivamente. [1](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=48my7ob3UD6UaFJtWl)
>
> El plural es bereberes y beréberes, respectivamente.[2](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=RVB5BqWekD62kWhaTn)
>
> en estos casos debió decirse rivales encarnizados y encarnizamiento médico, respectivamente.[3](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=encarnizar)

Aunque hay ejemplos donde no la usan [editado para usar un ejemplo de la RAE]:

> Se dice berrido y chasquido (no *berreído y *chasqueído) porque estos sustantivos proceden de berrar y chascar respectivamente ...[4](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/z.cgi?t=5235822578270510618132232&s=1&ap=5.9l)

A mi me suena mejor con la coma, pero no tengo una explicación del porqué.

Comment: Walen, actualicé el último ejemplo con uno que no cite un texto ajeno.